# Can't upgrade PHP on Mac

Tags: php, apache

I've tried all the solutions of upgrading my PHP on my mac, following this tutorial now: http://php-osx.liip.ch/. I've also written export PATH=/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH in my ~/.profile.

Right now it looks like this:

```
# MacPorts Installer addition on 2012-10-24_at_12:03:59: adding an appropriate PATH variable for use with MacPorts.
#export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
export PATH=/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH
# Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.
```

But when I do "php -v", it still shows me:

```
PHP 5.3.15 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Jul 31 2012 14:49:18)
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
```

when it should be saying

```
PHP 5.5.0 (cli) (built: Jun 21 2013 13:11:59)
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0-dev, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.2.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2013, by Derick Rethans
```

Please help, I've tried everything.

Comment: what does `which php` say?

Comment: I added quotation marks and it works now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed it to export PATH="/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH" and it works now!